# Usar Try en re-direccion a segunda base de datos

Tags: c#, sql-server, try-catch

Necesito hacer una conexión de respaldo en caso de que la primera falle usando try-catch cosa que ni idea de como hacer, use unos tutos pero son para cuando es el insert el que falla, si alguien me puede asesorar se los agradecería mucho. estoy usqndo sql server 2014 y visual studio 2019

```
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
            cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-OARKNOH;Initial Catalog=BDBase;Integrated Security=True";
            string servidor = ConfigurationManager.Instancia.getServer;
            string database = ConfigurationManager.Instancia.getDatabase;
            string user = ConfigurationManager.Instancia.getUser;
            string clave = ConfigurationManager.Instancia.getClave;
            return cn;

            try
            {

                    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
                    cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-OARKNOH2;Initial Catalog=BDBase;Integrated Security=True";
                    string servidor = ConfigurationManager.Instancia.getServer;
                    string database = ConfigurationManager.Instancia.getDatabase;
                    string user = ConfigurationManager.Instancia.getUser;
                    string clave = ConfigurationManager.Instancia.getClave;
                    return cn;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
                cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-OARKNOH;Initial Catalog=BDBase;Integrated Security=True";
                string servidor = ConfigurationManager.Instancia.getServer;
                string database = ConfigurationManager.Instancia.getDatabase;
                string user = ConfigurationManager.Instancia.getUser;
                string clave = ConfigurationManager.Instancia.getClave;
                return cn;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Pues el código que muestras es el encargado de retornar una instancia de la conexión y no tiene nada que ver con la operación que vayas a intentar. Entonces, qué problema tienes al usar tu código?

Comment: Pues entonces, intenta usarlo y nos cuentas qué problema estás intentando resolver. Hacerte los deberes no es la idea del sitio :) A los que nos pagan por programar no nos toca muy diferente.

Comment: en ninguno dije que lo hicieran sino que si alguien sabe usar el try para algo asi, yo intente asi basando me en los ejemplo que hay, incluso en la practica manda es diferente por que es  consultar la insercion de datos no la coneccion establecia y su respaldo

Comment: El código que muestras intenta establecer una conexión y retorna la instancia a quien sea que la quiera usar. Si es para un insert o no, a ese código le es indiferente. A eso me refiero con que no es claro cuál es tu objetivo (el de tu práctica) y por qué el código que muestras no es suficiente (y por eso haces esta pregunta). Sin eso es muy difícil ayudarte.

Comment: a ya, el objetivo es que cuando no te puedas conectara la base de datos principal te conectes a una segunda base que tiene los mismos datos

Comment: El código que muestras está raro porque primero crea la conexión y la retorna, y luego hace el try-catch que sería lo que realmente buscas. Usando sólo el try-catch debería funcionar el elegir la conexión que esté disponible. Habría que preocuparse además por cómo hacer que las dos BD siempre tengan los mismos datos y no sé si les importe validar qué pasa si no hay conexión a ninguna de las dos

Comment: a lo de las bases ya esta, eso si me salio bien se actualizan cuando hay cambios, y si se que el código esta raro, yo pensé en hacer con un if pero el profe mando que debe se mas o menos asi

Comment: Esto no se soluciona por código sino por infraestructura. Investiga acerca de failover clusters en SQL Server.